# Call to a member function toArray() on array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I’m trying to use this package: `https://packagist.org/packages/digital-creative/conditional-container`. However with this basic example:

```
    return array_merge(
        [

            Select::make('Option', 'option')
              ->options([
                  1 => 'Option 1',
                  2 => 'Option 2',
                  3 => 'Option 3',
              ]),

        /**
         * Only show field Text::make('Field A') if the value of option is equals 1
         */
        ConditionalContainer::make([ Text::make('Field A') ])->if('option = 1'),
        Text::make('Title'),
        Textarea::make('Description'),
        ],
        $arr
    );
```

I’m getting the error message: `Call to a member function toArray() on array`.

If I change to:

```
return array_merge(
            [

                [
                    Select::make('Option', 'option')
                  ->options([
                      1 => 'Option 1',
                      2 => 'Option 2',
                      3 => 'Option 3',
                  ]),
                  ConditionalContainer::make([ Text::make('Field A') ])->if('option = 1')
                ],
```

It shows:

```
message: "Call to a member function getUpdateRules() on array"
```

even with only the example like below it shows "message: "Call to a member function toArray() on array":

```
 public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
                    Select::make('Option', 'option')
                  ->options([
                      1 => 'Option 1',
                      2 => 'Option 2',
                      3 => 'Option 3',
                  ]),
                  
                  ConditionalContainer::make([ Text::make('Field A') ])->if('option = 1')
                ];
    }
```

Do you know how to solve the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is does, but you are sending an array to a class that class has a method toArray().

that's why i always use return types in my code cause it will break if the input does not match.

Could it be that it thinks that this is a collection or a class that needs to be inputted.

in some cases i am lazy and will try the following:

```php
collect(return array_merge(
            [

                [
                    Select::make('Option', 'option')
                  ->options([
                      1 => 'Option 1',
                      2 => 'Option 2',
                      3 => 'Option 3',
                  ]),
                  ConditionalContainer::make([ Text::make('Field A') ])->if('option = 1')
                ],)
```

because many packages uses Collection as a way to handle, filter and search an array.

but this is more a guess than actuall knowledge. Look at the function getUpdateRules() in the vendor map, what does it do.

```php
/**
     * @param Resource|Model $resource
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function resolveDependencyFieldUsingResource($resource): array
    {

        $matched = $this->runConditions(
            $this->flattenRelationships($resource)
        );

        return $matched ? $this->fields->toArray() : [];

    }
```

this is the function so as you can see it expects a model or resource class

according to the docs:

```php
return [
    
            Select::make('Option', 'option')
                  ->options([
                      1 => 'Option 1',
                      2 => 'Option 2',
                      3 => 'Option 3',
                  ]),
    //more suff
```

your return array

```
array_merge(
            [ // <--- note the extra bracket

                [
                    Select::make('Option', 'option')
                  ->options([
                      1 => 'Option 1',
                      2 => 'Option 2',
                      3 => 'Option 3',
                  ]),
                  ConditionalContainer::make([ Text::make('Field A') ])->if('option = 1')
                ],
```

Comment: Thanks, but it shows a syntax error like that.

Comment: getUpdateRules() that function is not in the package, did you create this?

Comment: Here it shows like that "{message: "Call to a member function toArray() on array", exception: "Error",…}
exception: "Error"
file: "/var/www/vendor/digital-creative/conditional-container/src/ConditionalContainer.php"
line: 354
message: "Call to a member function toArray() on array". So it seems that its in the packge right?

Comment: I edited my awnser

Comment: so look at your output of the array merge I think you have to look there for the awnser

Comment: Thanks, like that it shows a different error "message: "array_merge(): Argument #2 must be of type array, Laravel\\Nova\\Fields\\Text given"
".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242372/discussion-between-ozzdev-and-marcel-santing).